# Syntax error in code, unable to find a solution

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm currently trying to get a bot to work but I'm stuck and was wondering if anyone can help:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

 #@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Deletes the command from the channel
    if message.content.startswith(!)
        await message.delete()

    await bot.process_commands(message)

client.run('Client/////key')
```

The output I get is:

```
jeff@Bot-Host:~/Command Destroyer/Command-Destroyer$ python3 CD.py
  File "CD.py", line 12
    if message.content.startswith(!)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use quotes, a  string.

Comment: put quotes around the punctuation mark: `'!'`

Comment: You need quotes around the exclamation mark like so `"!"`, and you also need a colon at the end of the if condition.

Comment: and also `:` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Change line 12 to `if message.content.startswith('!'):`

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to wrap that `!` in quotes, like so:
`if message.content.startswith('!'):`

[`startswith`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm) expects a string as the first argument.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to have to put a colon after the if statement... Hope it helps..thanks

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue!